# how to upgrade to Qt 5.5.1

Tags: 32-bit, qt5

I already have Qt 5.5.0 on my Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (32-bit) and want to upgrade it to Qt 5.5.1 (I don't need to install Qt creator necessarily). Can anyone help me to find a proper way? I'm new in Qt.

Comment: You may want to check out [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/) Unless you have a very clear and specific need for that package version, it's best to leave it alone. Going with a different package version than repos can cause problems if that package has a lot of dependencies or if other packages are dependent on it.

Comment: Are you sure your details are correct?  Kubuntu 18.04 LTS ([which is EOL as is all of Qt5 in *bionic*](https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-reaches-end-of-kubuntu-support/)) came with a later LTS release of Qt5 than you mention; are you sure you're not asking about Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, my machine is "Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS" 32-bit. What I need is to have newer version of "qmake". The qmake that I already have is:
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.0 in /home/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib

Comment: **universe** : The current qt5 seems to be version 5.9.5   https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/qt5-default